# Simple solution needed for jBPM asynchronous continuations in Seam environment

Tags: asynchronous, seam, continuations, jbpm

I have a Seam application that kicks off business processes. At the moment there is no other application or component that needs to co-ordinate, there is just the one web app.

I'd like to use asynchronous continuations in the business processes, but at the moment if I do the process just sits there inactive and the relevant actions are not executed.

How do "switch on" asynchronous continuations in a Seam environment?

I've seen this [article](http://jogeraerts.blogspot.com/2007/10/jboss-seam-and-jbpm-async-nodes.html), but cannot locate any of the classes mentioned and am a bit stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually stumbled into a work-around attached to [JBSEAM-3837](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBSEAM-3837), but only **after** giving up Googling, attempting to write a Seam component like that one myself, then giving up on that and opting for a standalone version.

Talk about irritating!